# Using free TTS makse program unresponsive

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts

I am creating a tts program. I am using [free tts](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php). The program is fine, running.
I have assigned two buttons(start,stop) and a text box. The start button reads the text from the text box and sent it to the free tts algorithm to convert to speech.

**It all works fine but the problem is that once I have click on start, the program starts reading and it becomes unresponsive until reading is completed, I cannot even click the stop button.**

I tried to solve this problem by sending word by word to the tts algorithm but the the speech is really unbearable

How do I solve this problem???

Comment: It looks like you are running TTS in the UI thread, i.e. have you created a new TTSReaderThread in the onClick event handler?

Comment: @Cebence Yes, I have done that. How do I rectify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be corrected using **SwingWorker**.
I is a really effective methood.

Detailed help is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [here](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)